# code coverage tool for java webstart/jnlp application

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have been searching for some time for a code coverage tool that will work with my client/sever application, but I have been unable to find a compatible tool.

My application stores images on a server, then displays them though a client which is launched via java webstart/jnlp file.

Any recommendations would be appreciated. I have already tried emma & clover, with no results. open source or commercials solutions are acceptable. thanks!

Comment: What does "no results" mean? Are you looking to instrument the JARs that are delivered via JNLP? That would be unusual, but I know that Emma allows you to instrument a JAR manually. The real problem with that would be getting the test results back from the client.

Comment: I want to instrument the jars delivered by the jnlp, correct. I need a metric to prove that the application is getting tested to management, and code coverage stats would do quite nicely.

Comment: How you start your application if you want do the code coverage? It should work every tool if you start it without a browser from the command line.

Comment: I agree with *Horcrux7*: have your testers start from the command line rather than JNLP. Then they need to submit their coverage stats files back to you for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Instrument the classes with any of the code coverage tools you like (e.g. cobertura, which writes a local file cobertura.ser which can then be used for the report generation in a separate step).

Then, instead of running the signed or unsigned (which wouldn't work anyway) Applet directly in the browser, use the AppletViewer environment. The viewer runs the Applet in a privileged environment, without the Java Plugin Sandbox and thus the code coverage tool can do its work and write the report file.

Many of the code coverage tools use byte-code weaving and only write their results using a shutdown hook - when the VM shuts down. That is probably not working when used in a browser, since that's a special VM. Not sure, but maybe the Java Plugin starts a separate VM for Applets which is never being shut down.